# Apple Auto Renewable Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I am developing he application which delivers the video media over http(it is a streaming of movies).

I have used Auto Renewable subscriptions in the app and they are renewing on monhly basis also we are updating the movies inside the app continiously.

I was going through the Apple policy for auto renwing subscription which is,

> 11.7: Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type Appler In-App Purchase is currently an Auto-Renewable Subscription. However, it would be more appropriate to use the Non-Renewing Subscription In-App Purchase type. Auto-Renewable Subscriptions are intended for periodical apps, such as magazines and newspapers.

What does it mean?

Can my product will get approval or not?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same response from Apple.  To be clear, yes your app has been **rejected** and will not be allowed on the store until you make changes and re-submit.  Apple typically recommends in this case that you implement `Non-Renewing Subscriptions`.

If you strongly disagree you can appeal to the `Apple Review Board` but this takes longer than a typical review, and in my case, they still asked me to change the app.

Be aware.  There are some significant differences between Manual and Auto-Renewing Subscriptions.  Some are advantages, some are disadvantages.

With `Non-Renewing Subscriptions` (NRS's):

- Apple will not automatically send renewal receipts to all the user's devices.
- Since the `restoreTransactions` method doesn't work with NRS's, you can't ask for the latest receipt either.
- So you have to find your own way of telling when the same user is using your app on different devices.  Apple essentially insists that you do this by implementing an **optional** login system.
- There are other differences I haven't covered.

My first app rejection was because I had inappropriately used `Auto-Renewing Subscriptions`. And my second rejection was because they didn't like how I was syncing subscriptions across multiple devices. (I was storing a unique ID in the users iCloud account to identify when the same user was using multiple devices).